# php regexp to not allow DOT in string

Tags: php, regex

Here is my code at the moment, allowing ONLY a-z and 0-9. If I wanted a similar regExp that will NOT allow any string containing a dot (.) how would I have to modify it?

```
if ( preg_match('/^[a-z0-9_]+$/',$myExtraField) == false ) {
```

This is inside a symfony2 form class, not sure whether the regExp is the same as flat PHP hence I included my present regExp... never had the time to dive into regExp and hardly ever use it.

Comment: You're asking a pattern which allow all the characters except a dot?

Comment: Why don't you make another regexp: `/\./` and then check if the first is false and the second is true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest check you could do would be

```
strpos($myExtraField, ".") === false
```

If you really wanted to use a regex, you could invert `preg_match("/\./")` or just do a check like `preg_match("/^[^.]*$/")`

Comment: you're right, I feel stupid now... So I will instead use  if ( strpos($myExtraField, ".") !== false ) {

Answer (score 2):

In a regex, you can exclude a character by using the `^`.

So `/^[^.]+$/` will match any string that do not contain any dot.

- The first `^` means 'start of the string'
- `[^.]+` means at leat one char
- `$` means end of the string

Use a `*` instead of the `+` if you want to match the empty string.

Comment: I guess you don't need the first ^  and the $

Comment: You need it since /[^.]+/ will match anything that has a least one char that is not a dot.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, your regex also allows the underscore ("_") character.

If you want a regex that will disallow a dot, you can simply test for the existence of a dot, and change the sense of your test:

```
if ( preg_match('/\./',$myExtraField) == true ) {
```

Alternately, it may be more performant to use `strpos`:

```
if (strrpos($myExtraField, '.') == -1) {
```

then no '.' is present...

Answer (score 0):

If you must use a regex, then use the following:

```
if (preg_match('/^[^.]*$/',$myExtraField)) {
    // doesn't contain period
} else {
    // does contain period
}
```

Expression:

```
^[^.]*$
```

Visualization:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: @user689: Not sure what you were trying to do with the edit. Could you explain? :)